# Are this firebase rules & the PUT and GET request correct? (Angular + Firebase)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I want the user to only see his own posts and noone should access his posts.
Auth + posting is possible already and working. But without firebase restrictions.

For firebase I plan on using this rules. Is that alright?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "notes": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Put request in angular:

```
this.http
      .put(
        'https://_____.firebaseio.com/notes.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>',
        notes
      )
```

Get request in angular (here in the complete function)

```
loadNotes() {
    return this.http
      .get<Note[]>(
        'https://______.firebaseio.com/notes.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>'
      )
      .pipe(
        map(notes => {
          return notes.map(note => {
            return {
              ...note
            };
          });
        }),
        tap(notes => {
          this.noteService.setNotes(notes);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

I think the most critical points here are the links to the firebase database and the firebase rules.

I really would appreciate some help!! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `put` call tries to write to `/notes`, but your security rules don't provide anyone write access to that node. So the write correctly gets rejected.

To allow the write operation, you need to put the data to `/notes/$uid`:

```
  this.http
      .put(
        'https://_____.firebaseio.com/notes/uidOfUserInAuthToken.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>',
        notes
      )
```

In here `uidOfUserInAuthToken` should match the UID of the user whose `ID_TOKEN` you're sending with the request.

Comment: That looks great already! But there is still one problem: Even though in the console the <ID_TOKEN> is replaced by the users id, I still get the error: Could not parse auth token. Whats the problem now? I really don't know what might be missing.